# How to properly cancel Task.Run with deadlock inside

Tags: c#, lambda, delegates, .net-standard

I have a event that results in a deadlock when called and need a test to check for deadlock inside. But I don't have a way to influence the client code.

I already tried several hacks like

```
Task t = Task.Run((Action)(() => { while(true); }), cts.Token);
```

And ways to insert a token inside a delegate but since deadlock is called within delegate - any await never happens.

```
void Action()
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(url);(requestUrl);
    request.GetResponse();
    received = instance.RequestReceived;
}

instance.ClientRequeest += (object sender, EventArgs e) => instance.Stop();
```

I have a EventHandler ClientRequest I can subscribe to.
And an instance of a client that drops to deadlock when I try to stop it while it has some data to reply.

ClientRequest has a await inside - which, when asked to Stop and has a request - falls to infinite deadlock state - it awaits when request will be sent, and listener is already closed by Stop.
Which is a possible scenario in our case. But I don't seem to find a way how to call a that event without going to deadlock myself inside the test.

So would be pretty thankful for a proper way to make that Instance.ClientRequest wait for several seconds and throw exception or get cancelled or whatever - to avoid test hanging when deadlock actually happens.

Comment: Abort or safe cancel/rollback if client code partially completes?  (It’s even possible that the client code will fully complete if you just abort one side).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `Task`, and you know it will either complete in a fixed amount of time, or deadlock, you could:-

```
var t = Task.Run(() =>
{
    // do something that might deadlock, but if it doesn't will finish for sure in < 1000ms
});

if (!t.Wait(1000))
{
    // He's dead Jim
}
```